# Creating a playlist that can be controlled via Bluetooth earphone in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, bluetooth, html5-audio, playlist

I want to control the audio files these I added to my html page according to the commands I send from my Bluetooth earphone, but I could not find how to do this. What I mean is, I want to move on to the next or previous audio like on YouTube, is there a way to do this?

I added a few audio files to my page and tried to control them with my earphone. I can play and pause them with my earphone, but I cannot play the next or previous song.
Thank you all